# C++ vector.end() giving out of the range result - Please advise

Tags: c++, vector

In part of my code, I am using `push_back` to form a vector from a txt file:

```
while (!layerf.eof()) {             
    for (int i=0; i<kl.nlyr+1; i++) {
        std::getline(layerf,line);
        depth = atof(line.c_str()) - kl.depth;
        hlyr.push_back(depth);
    }
}
```

Let say I input {1,2,3,4}.

later, I need to find a value given as zz lies between which two element of the above vector hlyr, using the following part:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator loc;

loc = std::upper_bound (hlyr.begin(), hlyr.end(), zz);
```

Now the problem is hlyr.end is giving me nonsense value, 2 e-98, which is like it has not been intialized! My vector size is fine, even when I look at the vector in "watch' window in visual studio everything is right, but vector end is something nonsense.

If I resize the above vector to 4 nothing changes. But if I resize to 3, it will delete the last cell from the vector, and then the `vector.end()` will show 4! It seems `vector.end` is pointing to one cell after `vector.size`!

Is there an easy fix? I want to use it with the find algorithm I have.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end

Comment: Yes, that's *exactly* what `std::vector::end` does!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you are using hlyr.end() outside of the upper_bound. You may need to show more code.

Comment: Your use of the C++ standard library is wrong, as explained already. However, I'd like to add an advise: Most standard library implementations have a diagnostic mode which you should use for development. With that mode activated, you will pay a performance penalty but get various checks. Dereferencing past-the-end iterators is one error that gets detected by this diagnostic mode.

Answer (score 2):

`end()` on every STL collection is the iterator past the end of the collection; dereferencing it as you are doing is undefined behaviour.

You can do this to get an iterator to the last element in the vector, if the vector is not empty:

```
auto last = hylr.end();
--last;
```

If it is empty, more undefined behaviour!

"undefined behaviour" is standards-language for: you don't get to complain if it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I think `auto last = std::prev( hylr.end() );` is better

Answer (score 1):

It is normal with iterators for `end` to reference an illegal element, this allows it to be used as a way to express "not in this container". It also allows you to write:

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
```

if `end` was valid, you wouldn't be able to do the above.

In the case of a vector, it returns an iterator that references the first element beyond the end of the current vector. With your `upper_bound` call you simply need to check for `end` as an indicator that your value is above anything in the vector.

```
auto loc = std::upper_bound (hlyr.begin(), hlyr.end(), zz);
if (loc == hlyr.end())
    // there was nothing > zz in the vector
```

Answer (score -2):

hi you can define the variable depondon type that you needed and save the (hlyr.push_back(depth);) in it for example:
{int x = hlyr.push_back(depth); }